# Encog : Reinforcement Learning / Actor-Critic Model

Tags: java, neural-network, reinforcement-learning, encog

I have a basic neural net problem where I want a "rocket" to maintain it's altitude at a given height. (This is a simple version of the problem, it will get more complex).

I am using the encog platform and it isn't clear how to use it to implement reinforcement learning.

I think that I want to use the Actor-Critic model where two separate NNs exist. One of them analyzes the reward that's due according to the current state. The other NN calculates the force it should apply to the rocket.

I can calculate a reward schema (drive the distance between rocket and target height to 0). But I can't figure out how to make the "Actor" NN learn. It seems like I would take the error from the "Critic" NN and use that same error as the backpropagation error for the Actor. But I can't figure out how to do this in Encog.

Thanks so much for any help!

Comment: Have you looked at the Lunar Lander example?  http://www.heatonresearch.com/node/1299